# How I can block user access to an xml file via the URL of my website, But that software like Kodi can read it

Tags: xml, .htaccess, url, kodi, index.html

This question was already asked almost six years ago by Code Embassy. I'll take the liberty, if it's okay for you, to ask the question again. If over the years someone has found a solution or Code Embassy if you see this have you found the answer to your question despite these six years.

Is there a way to create an Htaccess or other solution in my File Manager from my server. To hide the information of an xml file by the URL. But that software like Kodi can read it for an Addon ?

Comment: The only way is to have two different credentials.  One that can read the xml and one that cannot read the xml.  The application (like Kodi) doesn't make a differences.  You are making a HTTP Connection which is the same with lots of different apps.  The app doesn't do the restriction, only the credentials (or Role) can be used to block access to a URL.

Comment: You could also somehow try to implement a conditional blocking rule based on headers you say are unique if the requests come from that application. But you should be aware that such measures are trivial to work around if someone wants to.